# "(405) Method Not Allowed" when accessing oData.svc

Tags: odata

I installed oData webservice in IIS on a Windows 2008 32 bit server using these instructions.

http://www.building-blocks.com/thinking/installing-the-sdl-tridion-2011-sp1-net-content-delivery-service/

I can browse to it on the browser. However when I try to add the service reference to a project locally on my computer, I get this error.

```
The HTML document does not contain Web service discovery information.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://servername:91/oData.svc'.
The remote server returned an unexpected response: (405) Method Not Allowed.
The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed.
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.
```

Has anyone encountered this before and what is the solution to this error?

Comment: That seems expected since the last screenshot in the Building Blocks example actually matches your error. How are you adding the service reference? See [SDLTridionWorld for a .NET example setup](http://sdltridionworld.com/articles/sdltridion2011/tutorials/using-odata-with-tridion-and-net.aspx). And an article by Nuno Linhares shows you [can query directly for pages](http://sdltridionworld.com/articles/sdltridion2011/tutorials/deployer-and-odata-5.aspx) by adding `/Pages` at the end of the url.

Comment: Thanks Alvin. Nuno's tutorial talks about installation using Tomcat-Apache. We already have the HttpUpload website setup on the deployer, content delivery databases everything. The only part we did was setup the oData webservice on port 91 in IIS. HttpUpload website is on port 81. Did we miss a step? Please let us know.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to add a reference to the VS2010 solution using this URL:

```
http://servername:91/odata.svc/$metadata
```

Comment: If this worked, please accept it as an answer.